# mail() with generated attachments aren't formatted on client mail

Tags: php

I have problem with mail with generated attachments, and sent by mail().
I use example 3 from [here](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php) .

And it works fine. But when I'd add some php definitions (like: $somthing = $_POST['sth']), the e-mail which is arrived, is not formatted, and it looks like source code.

```
<?php
    //session_start();
    include('funkcje.php');
    //$db=polaczMy();
    $nazwa = uzupelnij($_POST['nazwa']);
    $vorname= uzupelnij($_POST['vorname']);
    $strasse = uzupelnij($_POST['strasse']);
    $kod = uzupelnij($_POST['kod']);
    $tel = uzupelnij($_POST['tel']);
    $mail = uzupelnij($_POST['mail']);
    $datum_od  = uzupelnij($_POST['datum_od']);
    $datum_to  = uzupelnij($_POST['datum_to']); 
    $ort = uzupelnij($_POST['ort']);
    $zeit = uzupelnij($_POST['zeit']);
    $mietteilung = uzupelnij($_POST['mietteilung']);
    $service = uzupelnij($_POST['service']);

    function uzupelnij($przesyl){
        if(empty($przesyl)){ 
            $przesyl = "";
            return $przesyl;
        }
    }

        $to = '***@***.net'; 
        $subject = 'Anfrage';  
        $random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
        $headers = "From: ***@***.de\r\n"; 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
        $attachment = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\nN:".$vorname.";;;;\nFN:".$vorname."\nORG:".$nazwa."\nADR;TYPE=work:;;".$strasse.";".$ort.";;;\nEMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=WORK;type=internet:".$mail."\nTEL;type=WORK;type=pref:".$tel."\nEND:VCARD"; 
        ob_start();
        ?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
<h2>Hello World!</h2> 
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/vcard; name="attachment.vcf"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment  
<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 
<?php 
        //copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
        $message = ob_get_clean(); 
        //send the email 
        $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
        //if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
        echo $mail_sent ? "<span style=\"margin-top: 20px; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;\">Vielen Dank! Ihre Anfrage wurde versendet. Wir werden bald mit Ihnen Kontakt aufnehmen. </span>" : "Mail failed"; 
        //session_destroy();
// }
?>
```

and in mail:

```
 Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="PHP-mixed-26680626f5767c87be4bc162d5e80e8e"

--PHP-mixed-26680626f5767c87be4bc162d5e80e8e  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-26680626f5767c87be4bc162d5e80e8e" 
--PHP-alt-26680626f5767c87be4bc162d5e80e8e  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 
--PHP-alt-26680626f5767c87be4bc162d5e80e8e  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
<h2>Hello World!</h2> 
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 
--PHP-alt-26680626f5767c87be4bc162d5e80e8e-- 
--PHP-mixed-26680626f5767c87be4bc162d5e80e8e  
Content-Type: text/vcard; name="attachment.vcf"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment  
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:dgsdg;;;;
FN:dgsdg
ORG:bgdfg
ADR;TYPE=work:;;dgsdg;gdsg;;;
EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=WORK;type=internet:gsdgdf
TEL;type=WORK;type=pref:gfgs
END:VCARD 
--PHP-mixed-26680626f5767c87be4bc162d5e80e8e--
```

Comment: What part of the code did you edit?  It looks like the content-type header got appended to the body.

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails. it's too painful/ugly. use phpmailer or swiftmailer and reduce all of that code down to about 5 lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
$headers = "From: ***@***.de\r\n"; 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
```

this will result in empty line in your headers, so headers will end on `From` field, `Content-type` will be treated as body of the message.

You are also missing one empty line before each boundary marker.

and more importantly:

```
function uzupelnij($przesyl){
    if(empty($przesyl)){ 
        $przesyl = "";
        return $przesyl;
    }
}
```

What do you think it does? It returns null or empty string, so every variable you are assigning from POST data is empty.